# Beautiful soup: List all Attributes

Tags: python-3.x

I am a design researcher. I have several .txt files which contain 75-100 quotations to which I have given various tags like so:

```
<q 69_A F exercises positive> Well I think it’s very good. I thought that the exercises that Rosy did was very good. I looked at it a few times. I listened and I paid attention but I didn’t really do it on the regular. I didn’t do the exercises on a regular basis. </q>
```

I am trying to trying to list all the tags ("69_a" "exercises" "positive") by using beautifulsoup. But instead of giving me an output which looks like this:

```
69_a
exercises
positive
```

It is giving me an output which looks like this:

```
q
q
q
q
Finished...
```

Can you please help me fix this? I have a lot of qualitative data that I want to put through this. The objective is to export all the quotes to a .xlsx file and sort using pivot tables.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
file_object = open('Angela_Q_2.txt', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_object.read(), "lxml")
tag = soup.findAll('name')

for tag in soup.findAll(True):
    print(tag.name)
print('Finished')
```

Comment: Is it unclear what you are asking here. Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36597494/3100115) link on your question to show  sample of your file content and the expected output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you are wanting to list are called attributes not tags.  To access a tags attributes use the .attr value.

Use below as shown:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = '<q tag1 tag2>Quote1</q>dome other text<q tag1 tag3>quote2</q>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)

for tag in soup.findAll('q'):
    print(tag.attrs)
    print(tag.contents)
print('Finished')
```