# Split HTML by Regex

Tags: python, html, regex

So I have this HTML:

`div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org Offer"`

And I'm trying to split it in a list something like this:

```
[class="price", itemprop="offers", itemscope, itemtype="http://schema.org Offer"]
```

But I'm nost sure how to split the part of `itemscope`.

My current regex it looks like this `(\s.*?\"\s*.*?\s*\")`, but the problem with this one is that when I will split it into a list, the **itemscope** and **itemtype="http://schema.org Offer"** will be just one element, so my list will be something like this:

`[class="price", itemprop="offers", itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org Offer"]`

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: [I wouldn't recommend regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead.

Comment: I'm using already BS for something else. What I'm trying to do it here is to convert an HTML tag like that one into a XPath in order to automatize something. And in order to do that I need to split that HTML tag

Comment: You can get a list of attributes in BeautifulSoup, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597494/beautiful-soup-list-all-attributes).

Comment: See this question for a discussion of why regex is not the best tool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [lxml](https://lxml.de/) package offers some nice ways for dealing with xpaths and attributes on HTML elements.

Here is an example:

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

html = '<div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org Offer"></div>'

tree = etree.parse(StringIO(html), etree.HTMLParser())
doc = tree.getroot()

xpaths = [tree.getpath(element) for element in doc.iter()]

print(xpaths)

attributes_ = ([(f'@{att}', node.attrib[att]) for att in node.attrib]
               for node in doc.iter())
attributes = [item for item in attributes_ if item]
print(attributes)
```

OUTPUT:

> ['/html', '/html/body', '/html/body/div']
>
> [[('@class', 'price'), ('@itemprop', 'offers'), ('@itemscope', ''), ('@itemtype', 'http://schema.org Offer')]]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Beautiful Soup, Python includes [the `html.parser` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/html.parser.html?highlight=html) that has an HTML parser. Here is an example of how to use it.

(I changed the example HTML into a properly defined `div`.)

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    data = dict()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)
        for class_name, value in attrs:
            print(f'{class_name}: {value}')
            self.data[class_name] = value

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
html = '<div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org Offer"></div>'
parser.feed(html)
print(parser.data)
```

OUTPUT:

> Encountered a start tag: div
>
> class: price
>
> itemprop: offers
>
> itemscope: None
>
> itemtype: http://schema.org Offer
>
> Encountered an end tag : div
>
> {'class': 'price', 'itemprop': 'offers', 'itemscope': None, 'itemtype': 'http://schema.org Offer'}

Comment: Yeah... except it's a lot more work and not as robust... You might want to consider storing `data` on the object instance and not the class - might lead to surprises later on if it's re-used otherwise...

Comment: Please define "not as robust". Are you referring to the handling of broken HTML?

Comment: Yes...that's what I mean